# How can I use __getattr__ in functions in Python 3.1?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to redifine the **__*getattr*__** method, in a function.

I've tried this code:

```
def foo():
    print("foo")

def addMethod(obj, func):
    setattr(obj, func.__name__, types.MethodType(func, obj))

def __getattr__(obj, name):
    print(name)

addMethod(foo, __getattr__)

foo.bar
```

but I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File blah blah, line 14, in <module>
    foo.bar
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'bar'
```

I've inspected the "foo" function and it really has the method bounded to it, but it seems that if you set it dynamically, **__*getattr*__** won't get called.
If I do the same thing to a class, if I set the **__*getattr*__** using my "addMethod" function, the instance won't call the **__*getattr*__** too!, so the problem must be the dynamic call!

BUT if I put the **__*getattr*__** in the definition of the class, it will work, obviously.

The question is, how can I put the **__*getattr*__** to the function to make it work? I can't put it from the beginning because it's a function!, I don't know how to do this

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you don't. If you want attributes, make a class. If you want instances to be callable, define `__call__` for it.

```
class foo:
    def __call__(self):
        print("foo")

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        print(name)

f = foo()
f()   # foo
f.bar # bar
```

Comment: Never used the "call" method, I think that that will help me a lot, but I have to try. thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that Python will only look up `__xxx__` magic methods on the *class* of an object, not the object itself.  So even though you are setting `__getattr__` on the instance of `foo`, it will never be automatically called.

That is also the problem you are having with `class foo`:

```
class foo():
    pass

def addMethod(obj, func):
    setattr(obj, func.__name__, func)

def __getattr__(obj, name):
    print(name)

addMethod(foo, __getattr__)

foo.bar
```

Here Python is looking up `bar` on the *class* object foo which means . . .

the `__getattr__` method you added to `foo` is **not** getting called, instead Python is looking at `foo`'s metaclass, which is `type`.

If you change that last line to

```
foo().bar
```

and get an instance of the class of foo, it will work.